# Create API in Rails 4 - Uninitialized constant Api::V1::UsersController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, api, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

For a personal project I would like create a Restful web-service in Rails 4.

So, I created my first project using `rails-api` and add the following code:

**routes.rb** in *MyProject > config* directory

```
MyProject::Application.routes.draw do
    namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
        namespace :v1 do
            resources :users
        end
    end
end
```

**users_controller.rb** in *MyProject > app > controllers > api > v1 > users* directory

```
module Api
    module V1
        class UsersController < ApplicationController
            def index
            end

            def create
            end

            def show
            end

            def update
            end

            def delete
            end
        end 
    end
end
```

When I start the rails server with the command-line `rails s` and go to this URL: `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/show` I've got this error:

> uninitialized constant Api::V1::UsersController
>
> Rails.root: /Users/Jean/Development/MyProject
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace activesupport (4.0.4)
>   lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `const_get'
>   activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in`
>   block in constantize' activesupport (4.0.4)
>   lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `each' activesupport
>   (4.0.4) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in`inject'
>   activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in
>   `constantize' actionpack (4.0.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in`controller_reference'
>   actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in
>   `controller' actionpack (4.0.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:44:in`call' actionpack
>   (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
>   actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in`each'
>   actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
>   actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:674:in`
>   call' rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call' rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in`call' rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call' actionpack (4.0.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in`call'
>   activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
>   activerecord (4.0.4)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in`
>   call' activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:373:in
>   `call' actionpack (4.0.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in`block in call'
>   activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in
>   `_run__4323212420903942114__call__callbacks' activesupport (4.0.4)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in`run_callbacks' actionpack
>   (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
>   actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in`
>   call' actionpack (4.0.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call' actionpack
>   (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in`
>   call' actionpack (4.0.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
>   railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in`call_app' railties
>   (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call' activesupport
>   (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in`block in tagged'
>   activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in
>   `tagged' activesupport (4.0.4)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in`tagged' railties (4.0.4)
>   lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call' actionpack (4.0.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in`call' rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call' activesupport (4.0.4)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in`call' rack
>   (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call' actionpack (4.0.4)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in`call' railties (4.0.4)
>   lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call' railties (4.0.4)
>   lib/rails/application.rb:97:in`call' rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call' rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in`call' rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
>   /Users/Jean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in`
>   service'
>   /Users/Jean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in
>   `run'
>   /Users/Jean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in`
>   block in start_thread'

I found a lot of posts on Stackoverflow with the same error but the answers didn't help me solve my problem.

Thanks !

Answer (score 17, accepted):

if you have this path:

> MyProject > app > controllers > api > v1 > users

controller should be `class Api::V1::Users::UsersController`
 if this:

> MyProject > app > controllers > api > v1 > users_controller.rb

then `class Api::V1::UsersController`

For acronym name `API::V1::UsersController` instead `Api::V1::Users::UsersController` use inflectors:

in `config/initializers/inflections.rb`

```
 ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
   inflect.acronym 'API'
 end
```

Comment: Thanks you solved my problem! I finally removed the `user` directory and declare my controller like you said: `class Api::V1::UsersController`. But regarding this article: http://www.amberbit.com/blog/2014/2/19/building-and-documenting-api-in-rails/ the blogger creates the class `UsersController` using `module API` and `module V1` instead of `class Api::V1::UsersController`. Why ?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not enough clear in my first comment. What I was saying is that the blogger declare its class `module Api
    module V1
      class UsersController < ApplicationController
        ...
      end
    end
  end` instead of `class Api::V1::UsersController ... end` Why ?

Comment: oh i see, my bad, be careful this different thing.

Comment: Thanks, I just look at your link. So if I understood well, the way of declaring classes using `module` (like in the blog post that I put in my first comment) works only if `cache_classes` is set to true ?

Comment: @JeanLebrument so i think you understand right, try worked around this.